# How to send the data to TCP PORT using shell script commands

Tags: shell

I’m looking for a solution to send the data from a file to the **TCP port which is available on the specific server** using the shell script/Unix command.

When I checking for this option I found the below one but it’s not working out? Is there any solution is available?

The command I tried from a shell script and find the response below.

Option 1: exec cat /home/data/load.txt > **/dev/tcp**/$host/$port

-bash: : Name or service not known
-bash: /dev/tcp//: Invalid argument

Option 2:
**ncat -v -w 2** hostname 4053 < /home/data/test.txt

Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx:4053.
Ncat: Connection reset by peer.

It would be helpful if could someone help with this.

Thanks | SP

Comment: What is the listener expecting? Can you connect to it any other way (e.g. with a program) from this host? (No firewall issues, right?)

Comment: Can you run ncat in listen mode (`ncat -l 5000`) on the remote host and establish a connection?

Comment: It's working, I missed to check the listener end connection.